# How to combine these two arrays and echo them in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

How can I combine the following arrays? For example the first `$match` with the first `$register` and after that, to echo the array

```
$matches = array();
$registration = array();

preg_match_all('#(69\d{8}|21\d{8}|22\d{8}|23\d{8})#', $str2, $matches); 
preg_match_all('!<td class="registration">(.*?)</td>!is', $str2, $registration);


foreach ($matches[1] as $match) {
    echo $match.'<br>';
}
foreach ($registration[1] as $register) {
    echo $register.'<br>';
}
```

Comment: What u have now and expected output ?

Comment: Did you try the array_combine() function ? For scalar value, it could be usable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with this example :

```
foreach (array_combine($matches[1], $registrations[1]) as $matche => $registration) {
        echo $matche." - ".$registration;
    }
```

and an other post like as your : [Two arrays in foreach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480803/two-arrays-in-foreach-loop)

Comment: This is great. please can you show me how the code is changed if I combine more than two arrays?

Comment: I never tried with more two array. I don't want put a wrong code without test it. Try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6553752/array-combine-three-or-more-arrays-with-php. I don't think you are only with this problem :).

Comment: Can you pass your post as solved if the answer has help you? Thank's

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through one and get the same key from the other array.

```
foreach ($matches[1] as $key=>$match) {
    $register = $register[1][$key];

    echo $match.' '.$register.'<br>';
}
```

Comment: @RyanS: Oops, typo.  I meant `$key` :-P

Answer (score 1):

may be this will help you out

```
$array = array();
foreach ($matches[1] as $key => $match) {

     $array[] = array($match, $register[1][$i]);
}
var_dump($array);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `array_merge()` function .

```
$combinedArray = array_merge($matches, $registration);

foreach ($combinedArray as $row) {

}
```

https://codeupweb.wordpress.com/2017/07/14/merging-and-sorting-arrays-in-php/

Comment: Your answer is valid, but I would suggest adding a code example of `array_merge()` (possibly using the scenario that the OP uses in the posted question) to make your answer truly great. Remember, links are great for tracking source, but answers should be able to still stand alone and stay completely valid in the event of your link becoming invalid. Good luck!

Comment: This is perfect. Like I said, it is now a much better quality answer, and will be much more useful to future/potential users who land on this question/answer after a google search. Thanks for the extra effort.