# Looping through 2 matching arrays in PHP

Tags: php

I have 2 arrays, they are the same size, and each element corresponds to the same item in each array, ie, arrays look like

```
array1 => 'name', 'description', 'value' 
array2 => 'fred', 'manager', '100000'
```

So its basically a 2D array but they are separate due to the way they are built.

How do I iterate through them together so that I can join them like

```
name=fred, description=manager,
```

all in the same loop ?

**EDIT** Just realised i may have 3 arrays, array1, array2, array3, I assume that eliminates array_combine as an option ?

Comment: You can still do that see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6553752/array-combine-three-or-more-arrays-with-php but I do think other methods are easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for($x=0;$x<count($array1);$x++) {
$element1 = $array1[$x];
$element2 = $array2[$x];
//Now you can use these elements
}
```

or use `array_combine()`

```
$array3 = array_combine($array1,$array2);
for($x-0;$x<count($array3);$x++){
$element2 = $array3[$x];
$element1 = key($array[$x]);
}
```

or

```
$array3 = array_combine($array1,$array2);
foreach ($array3 as $element1 => $element2){
//Do what you want
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php

What you prefer find/easiest...

Comment: Note that if you use `array_combine`, you can use the `foreach` loop instead.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use [array_combine](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) PHP function.

Answer (score 0):

```
$array3 = array_combine($array1,$array2);
```