# how to Pass 3 arguments in array_combine, is that possible?

Tags: php, foreach, array-combine

i have three variables ($product_id, $size_id, $quantity) which get from "form" and insert into the pending_order table.So i used the array_combine function to combine three variables and than using for each loop to insert the multiple records. but it shows an error

> "Warning: array_combine() expects exactly 2 parameters, 3 given".

So im totally stuck, is that any other way to pass these three variables in array and than use for each loop to insert the record.

```
<form method="post" action="">

<input type="hidden" name="ip_address" value="<?php echo $ip_address; ?>">   
<input type="hidden" name="product_id[]" value="<?php echo $product_id; ?>">   
<input type="hidden" name="size_id[]" value="<?php echo $size_id; ?>"> 
<input type="hidden" name="quantity[]" value="<?php echo $quantity; ?>" >
<input type="submit"  name="submit" value="Confirm Your Order"> 

</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$product_id = $_POST['product_id'];
$size_id = $_POST['size_id'];
$ip_address = $_POST['ip_address'];
$quantity = $_POST['quantity'];

$array = array_combine($product_id, $size_id, $quantity);

foreach ($array as $h => $v) {

$insert_pending = "INSERT INTO pending_orders 
(cus_id,product_id,size_id,quantity,ip_address) VALUES 
('$cus_id','$h','$v','$quantity','$ip_address')";

 $run2 = mysqli_query($con, $insert_pending);

 }

if($run2===true){

 echo "<script>window.open('thanku.php','_self')</script>";
  }else{
 echo "<script>alert('Sorry, Try Again')</script>";

 }


 }
```

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6553752/3282633) ?

Comment: Thank u sir...problem solved @SulthanAllaudeen

Comment: Thank u so much @miken32

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just loop through one of the arrays, using the index from that array to access the corresponding values from the other arrays:

```
foreach ($product_id as $index => $h) {
    $v = $size_id[$index];
    $q = $quantity[$index];
    $insert_pending = "INSERT INTO pending_orders 
                            (cus_id,product_id,size_id,quantity,ip_address) VALUES 
                            ('$cus_id','$h','$v','$q','$ip_address')";
    $run2 = mysqli_query($con, $insert_pending);
}
```

Note that `$run2` will only have the status of the last `INSERT` query. So if they all fail but the last one you won't know. You might want to try adding this to the loop after the query:

```
if (!$run2) break;
```

and then in your error message you can indicate which insert failed e.g.

```
echo "<script>alert('Insert failed for id $cus_id on data $h, $v, $q')</script>";
```

Comment: OMG...Problem solved.Thank u soo soo much.i mean bundle of thankz. Thank u for your time and support.